# Error: Exception in EnvelopeIntegration.RunIntegration /api/docusign/webhook/v1/OnEnvelopeSent The remote server returned an error: (500)

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

While accessing webhooks getting error as
Error: Exception in EnvelopeIntegration.RunIntegration: 5609ec64-2a30-4c2f-a3af-5458969f3f6d :: https://be09-20-124-148-46.ngrok-free.app/api/docusign/webhook/v1/OnEnvelopeSent :: Error - The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.;

solution for authentication

Answer (score 0):

Internal DocuSign telemetry shows that the envelope ID is 5609ec64-2a30-4c2f-a3af-5458969f3f6d and that on 2024-02-13 you used the eSignature Settings app to resend the Connect notification message to your "listener" (your server).

It looks like your server responded with a `500` status (Internal Server Error). I agree that the "Exception in EnvelopeIntegration.RunIntegration" is not great.

But the main issue is for you to fix your server. Your server **must always** respond with a 200 status. 200 indicates that your server received the notification message.

After you acknowledge the message, your server can delete the notification if it is not needed. But in any case, you must respond with a 200 status otherwise, DocuSign will attempt to resend the notification message.

I suggest that you look at your ngrok logs. They will show the incoming message from DocuSign and your server's response.

If you don't see any incoming notification messages:

1. Switch your Connect configuration to use a test URL from https://webhook.site/
2. If it works then you know that the problem is with your server and/or network. If it does not work, then contact DocuSign Developer Support or try with a different envelope.

Comment: this is not about accessing envelope but it is about DocuSignClient.RequestJWTUserToken gives error as DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: 'Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code with response Body: {"error":"consent_required"}' from webapi

Comment: For consent required error, see https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent